# Magento slow login to admin (backend)

Tags: magento, authentication, admin, backend

It takes about 20 seconds to login to the admin. But when I log out and login again all is good. Can you tell me how to troubleshoot this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It bet you have a query caching issue (it has not been given enough resources). I would check your MySQL configuration and make sure you are giving MySQL enough memory.

Otherwise you can try and find the slow down by putting times into the code to find the slowdown. Usually I do this by using the microtime function so:

```
$start = microtime(true);

.... Code You Want To Time ....

$end = microstime(true);

echo "TIME: " . ($end - $start);
```

You may need to exit() after the echo so you don't have any kind of redirect keeping you from seeing this.

You can alternatively put the time into a log file.

```
Mage::log("TIME: " . ($end - $start), null, "yourlogfile.txt");
```

Your time will then appear in the file you specified in the var/log directory in your Magento directory.

Comment: Also, it sounds like Nick is having problems with a particular page. My answer would include to troubleshoot if it is one particular admin page that's taking too long.

Comment: I don't sure where is issue because development version of site works fine, though it is located on the same server with the live site , anyway, thanks for helping